# How to name the .a file when creating static library with g++?

Tags: g++, static-libraries, static-linking

Why is it necessary to have 'lib' as the first 3 letters of the .a created?
As in: http://segfault.in/2008/04/how-to-create-static-libraries-with-gcc/

Thanks

Comment: thanks, I never came across that question, but that answers it